# Error when casting generic types

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method `ExecCommand` that takes a `Command<CommandResult>` as argument. But it fails to build when I try to pass a command with a `CommandResult`-derived generic type:

```
class Program
{
    class CommandResult
    {
    }

    class Command<TResult> where TResult : CommandResult, new()
    {
        internal virtual TResult ParseReply(object reply)
        {
            return new TResult();
        }
        public Action<TResult> CommandCompleteCallback = null;
    }

    class CommandA : Command<CommandResult>
    {
    }

    class CommandResultForB : CommandResult
    {
    }

    class CommandB : Command<CommandResultForB>
    {
        internal override CommandResultForB ParseReply(object reply)
        {
            return new CommandResultForB();
        }
    }

    static Queue<Command<CommandResult>> commandQueue = new Queue<Command<CommandResult>>();

    static void ThreadLoop()
    {
        // This threadloop transmits the first command on the queue to external library when executeNextCommand is set (it's using Peek, so the command stays in the queue until the external library calls OnCommandCompleteResponse()
    }
    static void OnCommandCompleteRespose(object reply)
    {
        // called from external library when command is complete
        lock (commandQueue)
        {
            var command = commandQueue.Dequeue();
            if (command.CommandCompleteCallback != null)
                command.CommandCompleteCallback(command.ParseReply(reply));
        }
    }
    static void ExecCommand(Command<CommandResult> command)
    {
        lock (commandQueue)
        {
            commandQueue.Enqueue(command);
            if (commandQueue.Count == 1)
                executeNextCommand.Set();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExecCommand(new CommandA());
        ExecCommand(new CommandB()); // <-- this is the offending line
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I get the error 'Cannot convert from CommandB to Command'? Why isn't it possible to cast `CommandResultForB` to its base class `CommandResult` automatically?

Comment: Because generics are not C++ templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this exception is that by default generic parameters are *not* [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29):

Support for this was added in .net 3.5, but you'll need to define it via an interface and the [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) keyword:

```
interface ICommand<out TResult> where TResult : CommandResult, new()
{
   TResult ParseReply(object reply);
}


class Command<TResult> : ICommand<TResult> where TResult 
                       : CommandResult, new()
{}
```

Then you can update your ExecCommand method to expect the interface:

```
static void ExecCommand(ICommand<CommandResult> command){}
```

Once that's done your `ExecCommand` calls will work find:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExecCommand(new CommandA());
    ExecCommand(new CommandB()); // <-- works now           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call `ExecuteCommand()` with instances of the `CommandB` type and still be as generic as possible then use this:

```
static void ExecCommand<TResult>(Command<TResult> command) 
    where TResult : CommandResult, new()
{
    TResult res = command.ParseReply(null);
}
```

**NOTE**: This is an answer to your original question. It may help understand that part of the problem and may help someone else.

Comment: This is just moving the error to inside ExecCommand. There I'm queueing the command to a `Queue<Command<CommandResult>>` which then results in the same error

Comment: Well, you have the same problem in there then. Waht you can do is cast the result to CommandResult. I will post an edit for that.

Comment: That's too bad, because command also has a generic callback parameter which would then get `CommandResult` as argument instead of the correct type...